# Predicate in Service.OrmLite return enum value incorrectly

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack.OrmLite (version 3.8.5) and I have the following:

```
var report = dbCommand.Select<UploadedMediaReport>(x => x.Id == message.Id &&
                       (int)x.BitRate == (int)message.BitRate &&
                       (int)x.MediaFormat == (int)message.Format
                        ).FirstOrDefault();
```

where

```
public class UploadedMediaReport
{
    public MediaBitRate BitRate { get; }
    public MediaFormat Format { get; }
    ..
}
```

For the SQL generated, the string values of the enum is used rather than the int values ie. the wrong SQL is:

```
  select ... bitRate = 'High' and Format = 'MP4'
```

where it should be

```
  select ... bitRate = 1 and Format = 3
```

How do I change this so that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you are seeing is a bug, but a possible workaround is:

```
var report = dbCommand.Where<UploadedMediaReport>(
    new {
        Id = message.Id,
        BitRate = (int)message.BitRate,
        MediaFormat = (int)message.Format
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```